# Show that every diagonalizable operator is normal

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Could anyone show that a diagonalizable operator is normal in Hilbert spaces? Every hint is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by diagonalizable (definition wise) can you combine the operator and its adjoint operator to algebraically to show they commute?

Comment: An operator that is diagonalizable with respect to a nonorthonormal basis need not be normal.

Comment: I mean diagonalizable w.r.t  orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1):

If a (continuous) linear operator $A$ is normal (i.e. it commutes with its adjoint $[A,A^+]=0$), then it is diagonalizable. The converse however in general is not true. It is not true even for finite dimensional spaces. Consider the following operator $A$ in a 2-D H.S. given is some orthonormal basis by the following matrix:

$$A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\
3&4\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$A$ is diagonalizable (it has two different eigenvalues) and has $[A,A^+] \ne0$:

$$ [A,A^+] =
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\
3&4\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&3\\
2&4\\
\end{pmatrix} -
 \begin{pmatrix}
1&3\\
2&4\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\
3&4\\
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
-5&-3\\
-3&+5\\
\end{pmatrix} \ne 
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Therefore $A$ is not normal. In fact, most operator are diagonalizable, being non-diagonalizable is an oddity (in some sense it is a set of measure zero). At the same time most operators are not normal, even if they are diagonalizable.